# Uniform continuous function in convex set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question: Let $U$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Show that there is a constant $K < \infty$ so that $$x,y \in U, d(x,y) > K \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < K d(x,y)$$

Is there any way to proceed with this question? I am only aware of convex function instead of convex set. Furthermore, the hypothesis of $d(x,y) > K$ feels very weird. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of uniform continuity, for $\epsilon = 1$ we can find some $\delta > 0$ such that if $d(x,y) < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < 1$. Now, let us pick $K$ larger than $\frac{2}{\delta}$.

If we have two points $x,y$ with $d(x,y) > K$, we can connect them by a sequence of points $x = x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n = y$ along the line that joins them, with the property that $d(x_i,x_{i+1})< \delta$, and the number of such points needed is $n = \lceil \frac{d(x,y)}{\delta} \rceil$. Applying the triangle inequality $n$ times, we conclude that $|f(x) - f(y)| < n$. Since:

$$n = \lceil \frac{d(x,y)}{\delta} \rceil \leq Kd(x,y),$$

the proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you! Great solution.